# Callback after loading scripts works when preceded by alert and doesn't when I delete the alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, I load some scripts.  Then, once they're loaded, I bind those scripts to the relevant objects.  Everything works great when I have the alert() statement there, and fails (i.e. jEditable does not bind) when I don't.

```
// Load two scripts, execute editor_callback when both are loaded
$(document).ready(function() {

  var scripts = 0;

  var update_scripts = function() {
    scripts++;
    if (scripts == 2)  {
      editor_callback();
    }
  };

  // Load jEditable
  $.getScript('js/jquery.jeditable.min.js', update_scripts());

  // Load Elastic textareas (if needed)
  if (!jQuery().elastic) {
    $.getScript('js/jquery.elastic.js', update_scripts());
  }
  else {
    update_scripts();
  }

});

function editor_callback() {

  //alert ("In editor_callback()");

  $('.edit_area').editable('editable/update', { 
      type      : 'textarea',
      cancel    : 'Cancel',
      submit    : 'OK',
      indicator : 'Saving...',
      tooltip   : 'Click to edit...'
  });

  $('textarea').live("click", function() {$(this).elastic()});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its becouse you are executing the function right away and not waiting for the script to load.

Remove the `()` after `update_scripts`, so it will **point** to the `update_scripts` function, instead of **executing** it right away.

Your code should look like this

```
$.getScript('js/jquery.jeditable.min.js', update_scripts);
```

As to why adding the `alert` in the code works: `alert` paused the current code execution, so the next line (`.editable`) was waiting for the alert box to close, by that time the scripts were loaded already.

Comment: Fascinating - it worked - I never would have guessed that the ()'s were the problem, and that they could cause the function to execute right away rather than being a callback like I expected them to be from the argument list... fascinating...  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You could use console logging if you're using a javascript debugger that supports it (e.g. firebug or chrome) like this:

```
console.log("In editor_callback()")
```

Saves you from clicking the alerts as well.